# Styling composite views

Tags: android, android-layout, android-styles

I want to create a composite item and have different styles for it, but I don't see how to achieve it so far with a single style, I have to use different styles.

To illustrate my issue, I will define a sample scenario. Imagine I have a list with items, this items are users and I have an avatar, a username and an email. I want to style each of those 3 differenty deppending on my Theme.

**What I am trying to achieve:**

(file res/layout/item_user.xml, this will be inflated for a ListView)

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    style="@style/CustomStyleA">

    <ImageView
        style="avatarStyle"
        android:id="@+id/avatar"
        android:src="@drawable/avatar"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <TextView
        style="usernameStyle"
        android:id="@+id/username"
        android:text="Username"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/avatar"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <TextView
        style="emailStyle"
        android:id="@+id/email"
        android:text="fakemail@mail.com"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/avatar"
        android:layout_below="@id/username"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

(file res/values/styles.xml)

```
<resources>

    <!-- Style A -->
    <style name="CustomStyleA">
        <item name="avatarStyle">@style/CustomStyleA.Avatar</item>
        <item name="usernameStyle">@style/CustomStyleA.Username</item>
        <item name="emailStyle">@style/CustomStyleA.Email</item>
    </style>

    <style name="CustomStyleA.Avatar">
        <!-- Here avatar specific styles -->
    </style>

    <style name="CustomStyleA.Username" parent="android:TextAppearance">
        <!-- Here username specific styles -->
    </style>

    <style name="CustomStyleA.Email" parent="android:TextAppearance">
        <!-- Here email specific styles -->
    </style>

    <!-- Style B -->
    <style name="CustomStyleB">
        <item name="avatarStyle">@style/CustomStyleB.Avatar</item>
        <item name="usernameStyle">@style/CustomStyleB.Username</item>
        <item name="emailStyle">@style/CustomStyleB.Email</item>
    </style>

    <style name="CustomStyleB.Avatar">
        <!-- Here avatar specific styles -->
    </style>

    <style name="CustomStyleB.Username" parent="android:TextAppearance">
        <!-- Here username specific styles -->
    </style>

    <style name="CustomStyleB.Email" parent="android:TextAppearance">
        <!-- Here email specific styles -->
    </style>

</resources>
```

**What I actually have to do**

(file res/layout/item_user.xml, this will be inflated for a ListView)

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <ImageView
        style="@style/CustomStyleA.Avatar"
        android:id="@+id/avatar"
        android:src="@drawable/avatar"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <TextView
        style="@style/CustomStyleA.Email"
        android:id="@+id/username"
        android:text="Username"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/avatar"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <TextView
        style="@style/CustomStyleA.Email"
        android:id="@+id/email"
        android:text="fakemail@mail.com"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/avatar"
        android:layout_below="@id/username"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

(file res/values/styles.xml)

```
<resources>

    <!-- Style A -->

    <style name="CustomStyleA.Avatar">
        <!-- Here avatar specific styles -->
    </style>

    <style name="CustomStyleA.Username" parent="android:TextAppearance">
        <!-- Here username specific styles -->
    </style>

    <style name="CustomStyleA.Email" parent="android:TextAppearance">
        <!-- Here email specific styles -->
    </style>

    <!-- Style B -->

    <style name="CustomStyleB.Avatar">
        <!-- Here avatar specific styles -->
    </style>

    <style name="CustomStyleB.Username" parent="android:TextAppearance">
        <!-- Here username specific styles -->
    </style>

    <style name="CustomStyleB.Email" parent="android:TextAppearance">
        <!-- Here email specific styles -->
    </style>

</resources>
```

As you can see, the second scenario implies that if I want to change the whole style of the item, I have to do it individually for each view. I would like to change only the top style.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can define custom theme attributes for that. The views would then just reference the theme attribute and you can change the style by changing the theme attribute value.

First declare the custom theme attributes in res/values/attrs.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>

    <declare-styleable name="MyCustomAttributes">
        <attr name="avatarStyle" format="reference" />
        <attr name="usernameStyle" format="reference" />
        ...
    </declare-styleable>

</resources>
```

Then define them in your theme:

```
<!-- Application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="AppBaseTheme">
    <item name="avatarStyle">@style/CustomStyleA.Avatar</item>
    <item name="usernameStyle">@style/CustomStyleA.Username</item>
    ...
</style>
```

And reference them like this:

```
<ImageView
    style="?avatarStyle"
    android:id="@+id/avatar"
    android:src="@drawable/avatar"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

Comment: By the way, seems like assigning view-specific themes only works for API 21

Answer (score 0):

This is possible by defining your own theme and your own attributes.

This is your `styles.xml`

```
<resources>

    <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="android:Theme.Holo.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    </style>

    <!-- Style A -->
    <style name="CustomStyleA" parent="AppTheme">
        <item name="avatarStyle">@style/CustomStyleA.Avatar</item>
        <item name="usernameStyle">@style/CustomStyleA.Username</item>
        <item name="emailStyle">@style/CustomStyleA.Email</item>
    </style>

    <!-- Style B -->
    <style name="CustomStyleB" parent="AppTheme">
        <item name="avatarStyle">@style/CustomStyleB.Avatar</item>
        <item name="usernameStyle">@style/CustomStyleB.Username</item>
        <item name="emailStyle">@style/CustomStyleB.Email</item>
    </style>

    <style name="CustomStyleA.Avatar">
        <!-- Here avatar specific styles -->
    </style>

    <style name="CustomStyleA.Username" parent="android:TextAppearance">
        <!-- Here username specific styles -->
        <item name="android:textColor">@android:color/holo_red_dark</item>
    </style>

    <style name="CustomStyleA.Email" parent="android:TextAppearance">
        <!-- Here email specific styles -->
    </style>




    <style name="CustomStyleB.Avatar">
        <!-- Here avatar specific styles -->
    </style>

    <style name="CustomStyleB.Username" parent="android:TextAppearance">
        <!-- Here username specific styles -->
        <item name="android:textColor">@android:color/holo_blue_dark</item>
    </style>

    <style name="CustomStyleB.Email" parent="android:TextAppearance">
        <!-- Here email specific styles -->
    </style>

</resources>
```

avatarStyle, usernameStyle, emailStyle is attributes we never define. So let's define our attributes in `attrs.xml`.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <!--<declare-styleable name="AppTheme">-->
        <attr name="avatarStyle" format="reference"/>
        <attr name="usernameStyle" format="reference"/>
        <attr name="emailStyle" format="reference"/>
    <!--</declare-styleable>-->
</resources>
```

and your layout `layout/item_user.xml` as you mentioned

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    >

    <ImageView
        style="?attr/avatarStyle"
        android:id="@+id/avatar"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <TextView
        style="?attr/usernameStyle"
        android:id="@+id/username"
        android:text="Username"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/avatar"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <TextView
        style="?attr/emailStyle"
        android:id="@+id/email"
        android:text="fakemail@mail.com"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/avatar"
        android:layout_below="@id/username"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

And all you need is to switch your `android:theme` attribute in your activity tag in `AndroidManifest.xml` file.

```
android:theme="@style/CustomStyleB"
```

Comment: Although this also solves my question, the theme should be indicated on the item_user.xml file, not the activity. Because I wanted to have different items with different styles on the same activity. Thanks for the help.

Comment: You will have different items with different  styles but with different names. Actually when you put it in your AppTheme directly then it's global to all the app.